# Submit lib.nav to postUserFunc

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I would like to generate a main json with all content elements and navigation.
For this I generate a UserFunc

```
[globalString = GP:json=1]
lib.header >

# include jsonProcessor.php
includeLibs.jsonTools = /mobile-api.php

config.disableAllHeaderCode = 1
config.doctype = none

# set json header
config.additionalHeaders = Content-type:application/json

# keep typo3 from "tidying up" -> perfectly valid json
config.xhtml_cleaning = 0

# json encoder
page.stdWrap.postUserFunc = generateJson->pageToJson
[global]
```

Is it possible to submit in my ts the lib.nav to the postUserFunc?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumed `lib.nav` is a TS object you defined before the postUserFunc, you can pass this objects definition to your function as follows

```
# json encoder
page.stdWrap.postUserFunc = generateJson->pageToJson
page.stdWrap.postUserFunc.libNav < lib.nav
```

This definition will be available in the second parameter of the method `generateJson->pageToJson`

```
class generateJson {

function pageToJson($content, $config) {

   // analyse $config['libNav'] for the object type 
   ///and $config['libNav.'] for his definition

}

}
```

In case you  want to render this menu you must call tslib_cObj->cObjGetSingle() explicitely.

```
$local_cObj = t3lib_div::makeInstance('tslib_cObj');
$myNaviCode = $local_cObj->getObjGetsingle($config['libNav'],$config['libNav.']);
```